# How to access in PHP data returned in cursor from postgres function

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

Postgres function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lcp_product_find(IN pi_prd_code text DEFAULT NULL::text, OUT  po_cursor refcursor, OUT po_err_num integer, OUT po_err_desc text)
RETURNS record AS
$BODY$  
DECLARE
v_proc_name text;
v_prd_id integer;
BEGIN
v_proc_name := 'lcp_product_find';
po_cursor := 'po_cursor';

-- some selects from lct_products table

OPEN po_cursor FOR 
    select "PRD_ID", "PRD_FAMILY", "PRD_NAME", "PRD_DESC", "PRD_BRAND", 
    "PRD_MODEL", "PRD_STATUS", "PRD_AUDIT_CD", "PRD_AUDIT_MD", "PRD_CODE" 
    from lct_products where "PRD_ID" = v_prd_id;
    RETURN;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

In general, function returns product data in cursor (if any data found) and additionally err_number and err_desc if error occured.

Now I want to access from PHP data returned by function in po_cursor. What I am doing is:

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=name", "user", "pas");

$conn->beginTransaction();

$prd_code = $_POST['prd_code'];     //echo $prd_code;

// call the function
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select lcp_product_find(:pi_prd_code)");
$stmt->bindParam('pi_prd_code', $prd_code, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$cursors = $stmt->fetchAll();
$stmt->closeCursor();

?>
```

As a result I recive sth like that:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [lcp_product_find] => (po_cursor,,)
        [0] => (po_cursor,,)
    )

)
```

Can you help me in sorting that out? What am I doing wrong that I do not get data returned in po_cursor? Can it be done without PDO?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL cursor, once opened and returned to php, has to be handled by the SQL statements [FETCH](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-fetch.html), [MOVE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-move.html), [CLOSE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-close.html), ... through its name. This functionality is not implemented as PDO functions and besides is not compatible across databases.

[PDOStatement::closeCursor](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php) refers to client-side cursors which are not relevant in your context.

Example:

```
$s = $db->query("FETCH ALL FROM po_cursor");
$rows = $s->fetchAll();
$db->query("CLOSE po_cursor");
```

If using dynamic cursor names, be aware that they are SQL identifiers, syntaxically, which implies that they must be quoted the same as a column or table name when not strictly alphanumeric, and also that they're case-insensitive when not quoted.

[pg_escape_identifier](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-identifier.php) implements this quoting for the pg_* API but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent function in PDO.

When the program does not name cursors, PostgreSQL generates names like `<unnamed portal 1>`, whose spaces require quoting overall before being injectable into queries, like:

```
fetch all from "<unnamed portal 1>"
```