# Use returing parameter from stored procedure and use it in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, stored-procedures, cakephp-3.x

I have called a stored procedure inside cakephp3 model. I need to get the return value from stored procedure and use it in cakephp3, how to do it.

```
$conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$result = $conn->execute("call custom_sp($currentId, @msg)");
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, please *always use prepared statements*, you never know if the received value, or the called procedure might change at some point, which could possibly result in an SQL injection vulnerability!

That being said, it depends on what exactly your stored procedure does. If it only `SELECT`s the value into an `OUT` parameter, then you have to issue an additional `SELECT` statement and select the `@msg` variable.

```
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');

$statement = $connection->prepare('call custom_sp(:id, @msg)');
$statement->bindValue('id', 1, 'integer');
$statement->execute();
$statement->closeCursor();

$statement = $connection->execute('SELECT @msg');
$result = $statement->fetch('assoc');
$statement->closeCursor();
```

In case the stored procedure issues an additional `SELECT` query itself, then the second query wouldn't be neccessary, and you could fetch the data from the first statement:

```
$statement = $connection->prepare('call custom_sp(:id, @msg);');
$statement->bindValue('id', $currentId, 'integer');
$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetch('assoc');
$statement->closeCursor();
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Database Basics](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html)**

Comment: `$sql = 'SELECT "schema.function_name('refcur','id_of_post');fetch all in refcur';`
in my postgresql `function_name` returns the  result in `cursor` type variable `refcur` can you tell me how can in retrive the result in one above sql query when postgresql function result in cursor form

Comment: @Er.AmitJoshi I'm not overly familiar with postgres, I'd suggest that you first try to figure out how to do it in vanilla SQL, and then try to implement it using CakePHP. AFAICT you need to first fetch from the cursor (wich might be kind of an equivalent to using `SELECT @msg`): **https://stackoverflow.com/a/25603410/1392379**.